# Check if HTML attribute is inside quotes with Beautifoul Soup 4

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Take for example this two tags:

```
<input type="submit" value="aValue" />
```

and

```
<input type="submit" value=aValue />
```

I'm trying to get a True/False if a tag has an attribute without quotes. Using Beautifoul Soup 4 `find` method it prints me always aValue between quotes, event if I give second tag as input.

There is a way to catch tags with attribute without quotes?

Comment: You might ask about the greater issue you're trying to solve. This is a bit of a X/Y question.

Comment: I'm afraid that might not be possible with `beautifulsoup`. What's the reason to know this information?

Comment: The unquoted form of attribute values (that don't have any spaces) is legal in HTML. There is no way you could detect that condition with a DOM parser. It will recognize the name and value and put them into the attributes collection, details on how the attributes were quoted are irrelevant and are lost during parsing.

Comment: Nothing X/Y or greater issue, my goal is to know if  "aValue" is inside a double quote or not. Since my input string is HTML, I thought beautifulsoup could have help me.

Comment: This is the very definition of an X/Y issue. You want to do X, but ask about Y without ever telling what X is. The knowledge whether an attribute value was quoted or not is completely useless. You should never be in a situation where this makes any difference. If you believe that you are in such a situation, you need to explain what you intend to do.